# Создание/изменение графики C/C++ windows.h или graf.h

Tags: windows, c, c++

Доброго всем. Задача такова: Нужно окно с любой простой фигурой (прямоугольник) и 3-и кнопки. Первая - увеличивает объект, вторая уменьшает, третья закрывает программу. Можно использовать кнопки с клавиатуры, но предпочтительно нажатие курсора.

Вопрос как? Знаю как это должно работать, нужен код. С Win32 API (если это то) раньше не работал, в Си новенький. Нужна литература/статьи/примеры именно по данной программе, ничего лишнего.
Заранее благодарен.

P.S. Если знаете хороший учебник по API, то буду не против название

Comment: [RSDN>WinAPI с нуля](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/baseserv/api32.xml)

Answer (score 1):

- [Пошаговые руководства по Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e6w9eycd.aspx)
- [Примеры для Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee837238.aspx)
- [Создание приложения MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9es9d1k4(v=VS.100).aspx)